# Php Get Parameter with & symbol

Tags: php, html

I am sending a link in parameter to a php page like :

```
http:// exemple.com/test.php?url=http:// i-want-to-get-this-link.com
```

in php Page I get this link like this :

> $_GET['url'];

the problem some time the link has & symbol :

```
http:// exemple.com/test.php?url=http:// i-want-to-get-this-link .com/?page1&desc/otherstaff
```

so I only get the first part of the link : `http:// i-want-to-get-this-link.com/?page1`

how could I get the rest of the link `&desc/otherstaff`

Comment: do you have control in setting `?url` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php  Try looking at url encoding.  It should helping dealing with your issue of special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse_url()` function to get the query, if you cannot control the input url. Try this:
`print_r(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Answer (score 2):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your url variable to generate the url

```
<?php
    $url = 'http:// exemple.com/test.php?url='.urlencode('http://i-want-to-get-this-link.com');
?>
```

---

EDIT : you do not need urldecode with $_GET and $_REQUEST variables.

and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to get the original URL.

```
<?php
    $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you've been faster :)

Comment: From the manual: `Warning
The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.`

Answer (score 1):

When you create your whole url, try to `urlencode` it:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
then you can use:

```
urldecode($_GET['url']);
```